# CruiseControl [.Net] vs TeamCity for continuous integration as of 07/2015?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, cruisecontrol.net

The issue that I see with technology comparison questions is that they tend to be outdated relatively quickly in Stackoverflow - so much that I even feel the need for Stackoverflow framework itself should reopen the questions sometimes. And I feel since they all have accepted answers already, people do not bother answering them - and the comparisons are way off when today is compared to the past.

This question was asked before with most recent answers actually being in 2008 - with only a few partially recent minor edits which do not capture the essence of the newer versions for these technologies.

So can anyone with recent experience on these technologies comment on pros/cons and whether it is especially worth choosing one over the other.

I should also mention that in our project we are using TFS which has some support for Cruise control as well.